# Restricting access to some columns in a table, based on another column in the same row

Tags: postgresql, user-interface

This feels like it should be a common requirement, but I'm not sure how best to implement the requirement.

I'm going to make up a really simple example. It's similar enough to what I actually need, without getting over-complicated.

Imagine we have a table called `transport` and it has the following columns:

- type
- model_name
- size
- number_of_wheels
- fuel
- maximum_passenger_count

We want to store all sorts of different types of transportation in this table, but not every type will have values in every column. Imagine the commonality is a lot higher, as this is a bit of  fake example.

Here's a few examples of how this might work in practice:

- type = cycle, we ban fuel, as it's not relevant for a cycle
- type = bus, all columns are valid
- type = sledge, we ban number_of_wheels, as sledges don't have wheels, we also ban fuel
- type = car, all columns are valid

I want my UI to show a grid with a list of all the rows in the transport table. Users can edit the data directly in the grid and add new rows. When they add a new row, they're forced to pick the transport type in a dropdown before it appears in the grid. They then complete the details. All the values are optional, apart from the ones we explicitly don't want to record a value for, where we expect to not see anything at all.

I can see a number of ways to implement this, but none of them seems like a complete solution:

- I could put this logic into the UI, enabling/ disabling grid cells based on type. But there's nothing to stop someone directly inserting data into the "wrong" columns in the backend of the database or via the API, which would then come through into the UI unless I added a rule to also mask out values in disabled cells. Making changes to which columns are restricted per transport type would be very difficult
- I could put this logic into the API, raising an error if someone enters data into a cell that should be disallowed. This closes one gap for insertion to the database via the API, but SQL scripts would still allow entry into the "wrong" column. Also, the user experience would suck, as users would have to guess which columns to complete and which to leave blank. It would still be difficult to make changes to which columns are allowed/ restricted
- I could add a trigger to the database, maybe to set the values to NULL if they shouldn't be allowed, but this seems clunky and users would not understand what was happening
- I could add a generated column, but this doesn't help if I sometimes need to set a value and sometimes don't
- I could just allow the unnecessary data to be stored in the database, then hide it by using a view to report it back. It doesn't seem great, as users would still see data disappearing from the UI with no explanation
- I could add a second table, storing a matrix of which values are allowed and which are restricted by type. The API, UI and database could all implement this list using different mechanisms - this comes with the advantage of having a single place to make changes that will immediately be reflected across the entire system, but it's a lot of work and I have lots of these tables that work the same way

Comment: Generally you'd put a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on the table, *and* an input validation logic on the API (or error handling on the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements that checks which constraint was violated and return an appropriate message), *and* disable the input cells in the UI for better user experience.

Comment: You don't mention the word "normalisation" anywhere . If you aren't familiar, some googling and reading would be a good use of 30 minutes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: yeah, I'm thinking `CHECK CONSTRAINT`, validation on the API, and disabling cells in the UI is going to be the way to go. It's not ideal by any means and there's still the question over where the configuration matrix that controls what should be restricted and what should be enabled in the UI will live... I can see arguments for storing it in the database and arguments for storing it in code

Comment: ...and it's not a normalization problem :P

Comment: I think storing it in the code is the easiest and most flexible - that's the source of truth, in the data reprentation that you think is most fitting, from which the others can be generated.